# Canvas: Replace scaled image with larger image

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have a canvas where a draw an image.

The user can then zoom in or out on that image.

When they have stopped zooming I replace the zoomed image with a hi res version.

i.e. a 100x100 image gets scaled by 2, then when they stop I will replace that scaled image with an unscaled 200x200 version of it and render that in the canvas, where it exactly overlays where the zoomed version was previously so the user sees nothing other than the image suddenly 'sharpens'.

This all works perfectly at the moment when I am initially centering the image and then scaling around the center.

So I also want to allow scaling around the current mouse point rather than just the center, again I have that working perfectly in that I can zoom in and out on the image correctly.

My problem is when I then come to replace the image with the hi res version when its not zoomed on the center.

I can't figure out where to place it to get it back in the same position.

ie how to calculate the translate parameters.

I have the same size Canvas, I have an image that is twice the size as before, I have the mouse coordinates used in the last zoom operation, I have the scale used.

So how do I then place the large image exactly over the zoomed image?

TIA
Rob

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. 
Re-run the last zoom transform, then apply the inverted scale, then render the larger image.

```
ctx.translate(pt.x,pt.y);
ctx.scale(factor,factor);
ctx.translate(-pt.x,-pt.y);

ctx.scale(1/factor,1/factor);

ctx.drawImage(.....)

ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
```